# jQuery Validation bullet points

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I would like to create one bullet point for each error message using the jQuery Validation plugin.

If there is at least one error, I would like to append a series of bullet points, one bullet point for each error.

```
errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                  if(!$(".erorsbox")){
                    $(".last").append('<div class="errorsbox"></div>"')
                  } else {
                    $(".errorsbox").append("<li>"+error+"</li>");
                  }
               }
```

Comment: So what is not working?

Comment: that function is totally discarded.

Comment: It's "discarded" because `(!$(".erorsbox"))` will always be `false`.  Not to mention `errorsbox` is misspelled, you have a stray quote `"`, and `error` is an object, not text.

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to create one bullet point for each error message using the jQuery Validation plugin.

Then `errorPlacement` is not the correct approach for this.  `errorPlacement` is only used for manipulating the HTML markup that is used for all individual error messages that normally appear next to each element.

If you want to create a list of all messages, then you will need to use the `errorLabelContainer` and `wrapper` options.

`errorLabelContainer` puts all messages into a single unordered list (`ul`) inside your designated container, and `wrapper` puts each message into a list item (`li`) element.  Simply by using `errorLabelContainer`, the default messages no longer appear next to each element.

```
$('#myform').validate({
    rules: {
        ....
    },
    errorLabelContainer: "#messageBox",
    wrapper: "li"
});
```

**DEMO:  [jsfiddle.net/uc70fncs/](http://jsfiddle.net/uc70fncs/)**

---

**EDIT**:

It's a moot point as `errorPlacement` is not the proper approach, however, as far as why your original function is not working, see my comments below...

- You cannot test for an element's existence like this...

  ```
  if (! $(".erorsbox")) { ...
  ```

  Since the element does not exist, `$(".erorsbox")` simply gives you an ***empty*** jQuery object, which would always be `true` within the conditional.  So `(! $(".erorsbox"))` will *always* be `false` regardless of existence.

  There is usually never a need to test for an object's existence and create it programmatically... simply put the empty container element into your markup ahead of time.  It takes up no space until needed.

  However, if you still insist on testing for an element's existence with jQuery, you can [use `length`](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-test-whether-an-element-exists/): `if ($(".erorsbox").length) { ...`
- You misspelled your `errorsbox` as `erorsbox` within the selector above.
- You have a stray double-quote `"` immediately after `</div>` in this line...

  ```
  $(".last").append('<div class="errorsbox"></div>"')
  ```
- The `error` argument will not work like this...

  ```
  $(".errorsbox").append("<li>" + error + "</li>");
  ```

  The `error` argument represents a jQuery object, and in your markup, it would render as `<li>[object Object]</li>`.  To access the error message text, you would use `error.text()`.

After fixing all errors as noted above:

```
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    if (! $(".errorsbox").length) {
        $(".last").append('<div class="errorsbox"></div>')
    } else {
        $(".errorsbox").append("<li>" + error.text() + "</li>");
    }
}
```

[jsfiddle.net/gan5eb5v/](http://jsfiddle.net/gan5eb5v/)

Now it's working, but not very satisfactorily, as the error messages will infinitely repeat themselves due to the `append()` being triggered by the firing of `errorPlacement` on every `blur`, `keyup`, and `click` event.

For best results, [simply use `errorLabelContainer` and `wrapper` as noted above](http://jsfiddle.net/uc70fncs/).